# Implementing LastFM API to IOS app

Tags: objective-c, web-services

I have an IOS app and Im trying to implement LastFM API to search for track names, However Im not sure how to do this exactly. The tutorial im following is using rotten tomatoes as an example, which I got running fine. However when I try the same with LastFM it doesn't work. Any solutions? The API link I'm trying to use is this

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search&track=Believe&api_key=f3f936c8534e7cad4fff55861704cbf0&format=json

sample of my code below

```
#import "SongSearchService.h"

@implementation SongSearchService

@synthesize searchTerm;
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize results;

-(void)main {

    NSLog(@"Service has run");
    NSString *api_key = @"f3f936c8534e7cad4fff55861704cbf0";
    NSString *search_term = [searchTerm stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.search&track=Believe", api_key, search_term];

    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    if (responseData !=nil) {
        NSError *error =nil;
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                             options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        if (error) {
            [delegate serviceFinished:self withError:YES];
        } else {
            results = (NSArray *) [json valueForKey:@"Songs"];
            [delegate serviceFinished:self withError:NO];
        }
    } else {
        [delegate serviceFinished:self withError:YES];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Is responseData always nil? If not, what do you get back from the server? Try logging with something like: `NSLog(@"responseData: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData]);`

Comment: The exact problem is when I run the app and search for the song Believe, it returns as no results found.

Comment: does it return an empty "`Songs`" array or is it hitting one of the two error conditions you have in your code?

Comment: It doesn't return anything, and there are no errors that pop up in the code.

Comment: "Service has run" is showing in the log?

Comment: Service has run shows up, then after a while within the app it returns that there are no results. The long only shows service has run after running the search within the app.